# WordPress: Get post slug for name of module in Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, slug, post-type

Got a Custom Post Type called Post Modules or the slug of post-modules. In that I have created using Advanced Custom Fields a number of reusable modules to allow me to insert content in another CPT. Each module is basically a post.

What I want to do is grab the slug of the post within post-modules and display it as a class within my section. So it would be something like:

```
<section class="post-module-name"></section>
```

The title of the post would be acceptable as well.

So I came up with the following:

```
<section class="toolkit-module scroll-section <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> <?php echo $module_type; ?>" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-module-id="<?php echo $module_id; ?>" data-module-type="<?php echo $module_type; ?>">Content Goes Here</section>
```

But that pulls the title of the post that displays all these modules and not the module slugs / names themselves.

So if I have a post called "Videos" and I have two modules called let's say music-videos and sports-video, I want to incorporate music-videos in my first section's class and sports-videos in my second.

Is there some way I can pull that post slug coming from the post type and name of the module I'm actually pulling the data out of?

Answer (score 0):

Check out wp_query. You’ll need to use that to access custom post types.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you already have a `WP_Post` object you can use it as follows.

```
echo $post->post_type; // Outputs the actual type of a WP_Post object
echo $post->post_name; // Outputs the slug of the post;
```

You can take a look at all the properties [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/), in your specifc case you need something like:

```
<section class="toolkit-module scroll-section <?php echo $post->post_name; ?> <?php echo $post->post_type; ?>" data-index="<?php echo $i; ?>" data-module-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-module-type="<?php echo $post->post_type; ?>">Content Goes Here</section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that pulls the post type and name of the current post. I'm trying to pull the post type and name of the post where the ACF module resides. Which is different.

Comment: As long as you have the ID of the post you can always get this value using `get_post`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I use php echo $module_id; I can display the ID number of the module, which at the very least will show something unique. Still I can't locate any documentation anywhere about how to access ACF modules beyond using module_type and module_id.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. This did it.

```
$module_slug = $module->post_name;
```

then to display it:

```
<?php echo $module_slug; ?>
```